# How do I use wget with a list of URLs and their corresponding output files?

Tags: files, wget, download, links

Suppose `list_of_urls` looks like this:

```
http://www.url1.com/some.txt
http://www.url2.com/video.mp4
```

I know how to use that with:

```
wget -i list_of_urls
```

But, what if my `list_of_urls` has this, and they all return proper files like PDF's or videos:

```
http://www.url1.com/app?q=123&gibb=erish&gar=ble
http://www.url2.com/app?q=111&wha=tcha&mac=allit
```

For a single file I could do this:

```
wget -O some.txt "http://www.url1.com/app?q=123&gibb=erish&gar=ble"
```

How do I use `wget` to download that list of URLs and save the returned data to the proper local file?

Answer (score 42):

By default, wget writes to a file whose name is the last component of the URL that you pass to it. Many servers redirect URLs like `http://www.url1.com/app?q=123&gibb=erish&gar=ble` to a different URL with a nice-looking file name like `http://download.url1.com/files/something.pdf`. You can tell wget to use the name from the redirected URL (i.e. `something.pdf`) instead of `app?q=123&gibb=erish&gar=ble` by passing the `--trust-server-names` option. This isn't the default mode because, if used carelessly, it could lead to overwriting an unpredictable file name in the current directory; but if you trust the server or are working in a directory containing no other precious files, `--trust-server-names` is usually the right thing to use.

Some servers use a `Content-Disposition` header instead of redirection to specify a file name. Pass the `--content-disposition` option to make wget use this file name.

Thus:

```
wget --content-disposition --trust-server-names -i list_of_urls
```

If you still aren't getting nice-looking file names, you may want to specify your own. Suppose you have a file containing lines like

```
http://www.url1.com/app?q=123&gibb=erish&gar=ble foo.pdf
http://www.url2.com/app?q=111&wha=tcha&mac=allit bar.txt
```

To make wget download the files to the specified file names, assuming there are no whitespace characters in the URL or in the file names:

```
err=0
while read -r url filename tail; do
  wget -O "$filename" "$url" || err=1
done <list_of_urls_and_file_names
```

The `err` variable contains 0 if all downloads succeeded and 1 otherwise, you can `return $err` if you put this snippet in a function or `exit $err` if you put this snippet in a string.

If you don't want to specify anything other than the URLs, and you can't get nice names from the server, you can guess the file type and attempt to get at least meaningful extensions.

```
err=0
n=1
while read -r url; do
  if wget -O tmpfile "$url"; then
    ext=data
    case $(file -i tmpfile) in
      application/pdf) ext=pdf;;
      image/jpeg) ext=jpg;;
      text/html) ext=html;;
      text/*) ext=txt;;
    esac
    mv tmpfile "$n.$ext"
  else
    err=1
  fi
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

Add other types as desired. If your `file` command doesn't have the `-m` option, leave it out, and check what `file` returns on your system for the file types you're interested in. If you have a file `/etc/mime.types` on your system, you can read associations of MIME types to extensions from it instead of supplying your own list:

```
n=1
while read -r url; do
  if wget -O tmpfile "$url"; then
    mime_type=$(file -m tmpfile)
    ext=$(awk "$1 == \"$mime_type\" {print \$2; exit} END {print \"data\"}" /etc/mime.types)
    mv tmpfile "$n.$ext"
  else
    err=1
  fi
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately using a while loop doesn’t let to take advantage of the parallelism in newer wget versions 

Answer (score 3):

You could loop over the entries in your `list_of_urls`. Something like this:

```
while read -r url; do
    wget -O foo $url
done < list_of_urls
```

Note that you'll have to add your own way of determining `foo` for each entry of the `list_of_urls` (also, I'm assuming this is a file on your disk).

Comment: Here's a variation on that: create a little script with one line `wget -O $2 $1`.  In the list_of_urls file, make each line an url, whitespace, a filename (eg `http://url1/blah&blah=whatever some.pdf`.  Then use the same as above, replacing the wget line with `./thatscript.sh $url`. In this case `$url` is actually a line with an url and a filename, of course.

Comment: Variation 2: Put the urls and filenames on separate, alternating lines in list_of_urls file, then use `while read url; do read filename; wget -O $filename $url; done < list_of_urls`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `wget` option:

```
wget -r -i list_of_urls
```

Comment: This does not work: `-r` enables recursive download. The filenames are not set correctly.