# Wget with different filename, but same extension

Tags: filenames, wget

I need wget to save to a different folder, different filename, and same extension, but I do not have the filename before downloading.

---

For example, let's say I have:

```
http://ge.tt/api/1/files/someFile/0/blob?download
```

and I need to download it to an id, *"fj39ejd"* in the folder `downloads`.

What is the best way to go about saving it to:

```
/path/to/downloads/fj39ejd.[extension it had before downloading]
```

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Maybe I'm lost but, where are you expecting to get the file extension from if you don't have the filename available?

Comment: @j883376: presumably, the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: Have you tried putting together a shell script to download it to a temporary name and having some sort of case logic to rename it based off the output of the `file` command?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the local file to have the name chosen by the server, use [`wget --content-disposition --trust-server-names`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61132/how-do-i-use-wget-with-a-list-of-urls-and-their-corresponding-output-files/61180#61180).

If you want the server-chosen extension with a locally-chosen name, you'll have to rename afterward. The easiest way is to create an empty directory, call `wget` in that directory, and rename whatever file was created to what you want.

```
dir="$(TMPDIR=$PWD mktemp -d)" &&
  (cd "$dir" && wget --content-disposition --trust-server-names 'http://ge.tt/api/1/files/someFile/0/blob?download') &&
  set "$dir/"* &&
  mv "$1" "fj39ejd.${1#"$dir"/*.}" &&
  rmdir "$dir"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've actually come up with two plausible ways of doing this:

a) You can save it to the folder "*fj39ejd*" which looks like:

> downloads/fj39ejd/theFileNameThatWasBeing.Downloaded

or b) You can make a `tmp` folder, which would, in a while loop, check if it contains a file containing "*fj39ejd*" and then `explode` it, getting the extension. This one, however, is a bit expensive and the connection may time out.